# Adding a button to mapView and tapping on it throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, swift, skmaps

On SKMaps for iOS, I'm trying to add a button to implement a "find me" functionality. The button is rendered properly on the map, but when I tap on it, it throws an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error in something called `IBGMethodSwizzler`

[image: Thread 1 errors]

Any ideas if this is SKMaps related?

Where I initialise my map, I use this code

```
let findMeButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(53, 90, 44, 44))
findMeButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "find_me"), forState: .Normal)
findMeButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("findMe:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
self.mapView.addSubview(findMeButton)
```

And this is the findMe selector

```
func findMe(sender:UIButton) {
    println("this is never called")
}
```

Is there a known limitation to adding a UIButton as a subview of mapView?

Thanks :)

Comment: I would suggest not adding the button to the map view itself. Adding views to a view whose implementation you don't control can be dangerous. Maybe the map view does something like iterate over all of its subviews and perform some operation on them. You probably don't want your button caught up in that.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @rschmidt, I'll have that in mind. My first attempt was to add it to the mapView so I have it in all my instances of that view.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code snippet:

```
var positionMeButton: UIButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as! UIButton 
    positionMeButton.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame) - 60.0, 100.0, 40.0) 
    positionMeButton.setTitle("Position me", forState: UIControlState.Normal) 
    positionMeButton.addTarget(self, action:"positionMe", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside) 
    positionMeButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor() 
    positionMeButton.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleTopMargin 
    positionMeButton.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true 
    self.mapView.addSubview(positionMeButton); 

internal func positionMe() { 

}
```